# Tests in Xcode won't execute with a run-time error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

Every time I try to run tests, on any project, I get a strange run-time error.
I added this function to a totally new project (delete_me)

```swift
func easyAdd(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}
```

and this test

```swift
import
@testable import delete_me
...
    func test_easyAdd() {
        ...
        let sum: Int = easyAdd(x: 20, y: 30)
        XCTAssertEqual(sum, 50)
    }
```

I get a run-time error which is `Undefined symbol: delete_me.easyAdd(x: Swift.Int, y: Swift.Int) -> Swift.Int`
and a bit more debug error is

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "delete_me.easyAdd(x: Swift.Int, y: Swift.Int) -> Swift.Int", referenced from: Tests_iOS.Tests_iOS.test_easyAdd() -> () in Tests_iOS.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I feel like it has to be something about how my Xcode is installed, or some missing tools, or some tools installed in the wrong place, but I'm not sure which way to go with this problem.